# mpm_worker not working with php7

Tags: apache, php-7

I will run an vhost as an other user, not www-data
So i tried the mpm_worker, but this is not working with php7

Whats the problem?
Is this not possible to run mpm_worker with php7?

I will run every domain with another user.

My system ar Ubuntu 16.06

This is my vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName kirby.xxx.ch
  ServerAlias www.kirby.xxx.ch
  DocumentRoot /home/xxx/public_html/subdomain/kirby/

  <Directory /home/xxx/public_html/subdomain/kirby>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
  <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    AssignUserId xxx xxx
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

worker is a threaded mpm, if you haven't compiled php for thread-safety you should not try to use a threaded mpm like worker. PHP version is something irrelevant for Apache HTTPD, consider mod_php (a third party module from php for Apache) and php itself as a separate things always.

Nowadays, you should use apache 2.4.x + mpm_event w/ mod_proxy_fcgi --> php-fpm

This way Apache will use the most performant mpm and php will be processed by its own daemon (php-fpm).